# Open Graph Insights API

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

Is there a way to get the data provided in the Open Graph Insights section (For example: Likes and Comments on a custom OG Action) via a query API?

We'd like to do this without having to crawl the insights pages.